# Heroku and 123 Reg showing IIS page only on naked domain

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, https, iis, heroku

I've got a site set up with SSL that works as expected when manually typing in 'https://example.com' or 'http://example.com'.

However, when I navigate to just 'example.com' I get an IIS hosting page.

My DNS is set up through 123-reg and my site is hosted on Heroku.

AFAIK Heroku is a Linux-based server system so I'm genuinely confused where an IIS page would be coming from. It's not running any of my code when inspecting element and logging things out to the console.

It's just an IIS image.

My DNS records are as such:

```
@ CNAME example.com.herokudns.com
www CNAME www.example.com.herokudns.com
```

I also am using `express-sslify` to redirect to HTTPS however as my code isn't being run on the naked domain it's not able to redirect traffic.

Any ideas?

Comment: `@ CNAME example.com.herokudns.com` is invalid per the DNS standard, a `CNAME` record can not exist where there are other records, which is the case at apex with `SOA` and `NS` ones. A provider may either offer a solution close to it but not a `CNAME` or just ignore your invalid input. Since you do not provide the involved name, noone can double check your DNS configuration for you. Have a look at online tools Zonemaster and DNSViz.